# spring tools 3 add-on for spring tools 4 install error (sts4 plugin install error)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

During installation, this error occurs and the installation is not possible. How can we solve this?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Integration, Flex and Web Services Extension (optional) 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.integration.feature.feature.group 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Spring IDE Spring Configuration Editor (UI) 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui [3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE,3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Integration, Flex and Web Services Extension (optional) 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.integration.feature.feature.group 3.9.22.202204280911-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like it wants Eclipse Mylyn, but it is not installed.

Comment: I searched for Mylyn in the marketplace, and there are several.
I don't know what to download from here

Comment: In the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ add the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest) and try again. Eclipse Mylyn Task UI has been removed from the latest Eclipse IDE release. That's why you get this error.